# ffmpeg rtsp protocol command crushed in Windows

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, ffmpeg, build, rtsp

I downloaded build file(ffmpeg-20130902-git-fdd1aaf-win64-dev.7z) from ffmpeg.Zernoe.com, and build it.
When I command "ffmpeg -version", it shows normal message.
version is 'N-55966-gfdd1aaf'.

Thumbnail extraction and display Video frames are fine with Local Video file.
But when I try with rtsp protocol, it show Error like below.

```
Assertion pos >= 188 failed at /home/kyle/software/ffmpeg/source/ffmpeg-git/libavformat/mpegts.c:1865
```

So I tracked mpegts.c source. and line 1865 is below code.

```
 av_assert0(pos >= TS_PACKET_SIZE);
```

How can I fix this? or All of releases from Zernoe has this error?
Thanks.

P.S
My environment is Windows 7 64bit

======== Answers for Request ==================

Sorry, but I can not attach output message. 
Some reason I can not dragging in Windows console.

My command is

```
ffmpeg -ss 600 -f rtsp -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://old.hanafostv.com/ontv/10800/T63779_2_130718.ts.pac -vframes 1 C:\Users\...\Downloads\aaa.jpg
```

Comment: Please show your ffmpeg command and the complete console output.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I edited posting. My command is there and output print is nothing special but error message, the error is also in posting. "Assertion pos >= ...". Thanks

Comment: I assume you figured this out by now?